# Detect when the "@123" button is pressed on the iOS keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard

Is it possible to detect when the "@123" is pressed on the keyboard?  I have a custom input accessory view that I want to change depending what keyboard is shown to the user.

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255323/how-to-detect-when-the-ios-default-keyboard-type-switches-from-text-to-numbers

Comment: I am also trying to find out the possible option of the same issue. I want to manually trigger @123 button press event after launching keyboard. Did you find any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

To quote from the following link

You can register for the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` to be alerted when the current input mode changes."

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                     selector:@selector(inputModeDidChange:)
                                         name:UIKeyboardCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification
                                       object:nil];
```

and

```
- (void)inputModeDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    id obj = [notification object];
    if ([obj respondsToSelector:@selector(inputModeLastUsedPreference)]) {
    id mode = [obj performSelector:@selector(inputModeLastUsedPreference)];
        NSLog(@"mode: %@", mode);
    }
}
```

Possible duplicate, have you looked at

this post ([Detecting current iPhone input language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414876/detecting-current-iphone-input-language))
or 
this post ([how to detect when the iOS default keyboard type switches from text to numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255323/how-to-detect-when-the-ios-default-keyboard-type-switches-from-text-to-numbers))

Comment: `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification` is only notified when language changes, not when the keyboard changes from, say, alphabet to numbers.